# Indicated mean effective pressure

Tags: thermodynamics

The equation for indicated power is ̇ = ̅   . Where L is the piston stroke (m), A is the piston area (m2), N is the number of mechanical cycles per cylinder per second, and ̅ is the indicated mean effective pressure (imep).

How would you calculate the indicated mean effective pressure ̅ if you were given Net indicated mean effective pressure and Pumping indicated mean effective pressure for a 4-stroke engine?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which source have you been using? Ricardo? Chapman?

Comment: not with that equation.  My take on MEP is it was fine for deriving power but not good for anything in the real world.

Comment: The source is the Ricardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noob, can't comment, so here's an answer.

It's not the terminology I'm used to, but apparently GrossIMEP is just the work done in the two important strokes (squeeze bang)of a 4 stroke, NetIMEP is GIMEP-PMEP, and BMEP=NIMEP-FMEP.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation